# Sharding issue in mongo db

Tags: mongodb-query

When i am doing sharding then following error getting when using addShard function in mongodb:
Please help me

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "no such command: addShard",
"code" : 59,
"bad cmd" : {
    "addShard" : "<server name>"
}
```

Why this error is occuring ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are perhaps not connected to a mongos instance.

Ensure you are connected to a mongos (router). Here is an example of the code I use to implement sharding with reference to addShard. I included the remainder of the code for thoroughness.

```
//this adds members of a replica set as a shard
sh.addShard("rs0/serverShd4:27017,serverShd4b:27017,serverShd4c:27017")

//indexes
use mydb
db.mycoll.ensureIndex({s:"hashed"})

//The db name is "mydb"
sh.enableSharding("mydb")

//This is the shard key strategy deemed necessary by OI to date
sh.shardCollection( "mydb.mycoll", { s: "hashed" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

switched to db admin

> db.runCommand( { addshard : "localhost:10000" } )

{ "shardadded" : "shard0000", "ok" : 1 }

> db.runCommand( { addshard : "localhost:10001" } )

{ "shardadded" : "shard0001", "ok" : 1 }

should work. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/77102